# Cannot Use a static IP address outside of the node resource group

Tags: azure-aks

I am trying to use a static ip address for the dashboard that is created outside of the node resource group following the guide located [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/static-ip#use-a-static-ip-address-outside-of-the-node-resource-group), but it is not working. (This is for a firewalled dev-only cluster and won't go to production.)

What I have done so far:

1. Created a public ip address in resourcegroup1
2. Create an AKS cluster in resourcegroup1 tied to a azure ad application.
3. Added the azure ad application's service principal as a "Network Contributer" in resourcegroup1.
4. Added `service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-resource-group: resourcegroup1` to my service.yaml file.
5. Added loadBalancerIP with the ip address from step 1.

Whenever I apply service.yaml, the service says it's in a pending state. When I run `kubectl describe service`, it shows the following output:

```
Name:                        kubernetes-dashboard
Namespace:                   kube-system
Labels:                      <none>
Annotations:                 externalTrafficPolicy=Local
                             service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-resource-group=resourcegroup1
Selector:                    k8s-app=kubernetes-dashboard
Type:                        LoadBalancer
IP:                          10.0.42.112
IP:                          <IP FROM STEP 1>
Port:                        <unset>  80/TCP
TargetPort:                  9090/TCP
NodePort:                    <unset>  31836/TCP
Endpoints:                   10.244.0.6:9090
Session Affinity:            None
External Traffic Policy:     Cluster
LoadBalancer Source Ranges:  <SNIPPED>
Events:
  Type     Reason                      Age               From                Message
  ----     ------                      ----              ----                -------
  Normal   EnsuringLoadBalancer        38s (x6 over 3m)  service-controller  Ensuring load balancer
  Warning  CreatingLoadBalancerFailed  38s (x6 over 3m)  service-controller  Error creating load balancer (will retry): failed to ensure load balancer for service kube-system/kubernetes-dashboard: user supplied IP Address <IP FROM STEP 1> was not found
```

Here is my service.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: kubernetes-dashboard
  namespace: kube-system
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-resource-group: resourcegroup1
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  loadBalancerIP:  <IP FROM STEP 1>
  ports:
  - port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 9090
  selector:
    k8s-app: kubernetes-dashboard
  loadBalancerSourceRanges:
  - <SNIP>
  - <SNIP>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My AKS cluster was 1.9.x which was older than the required 1.10.x. I was using Terraform to create the cluster and there appears to be a bug with how a missing kubernetes_version is handled. I submitted an issue on their repo.

Answer (score 1):

For the error you got, it means the public IP cannot be found in the `resourcegroup1` with the same region as the AKS. Different region causes the error like this as yours:

[image]

So you should create public IP in the same region with your AKS. Then it will work for you.

Comment: My IP Address/AKS cluster are both in the same region, so that doesn't apply to my specific problem, but thank you for the idea!

Comment: @randomsolutions OK, so they are in the same subscription of a tenant? More details are needed to figure out the error.